# How emit resources to assemblies during Compilation with roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a C# application that I've compiled with Roslyn but after compilation it doesn't start and no window is shown.
I've found this exception in the logs:

> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException ... Make sure "    [Project].Properties.Resources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into
>   assembly "[Project]" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

```
//I have tested the below code but it doesn't work
//the exception is still thrown
List < string > ListOfResxFile = GetListOfResxFiles(project);
if (ListOfResxFile.Count == 0) {
    EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(jaryan);
} else {
    List < ResourceDescription > lr = new List < ResourceDescription > ();
    foreach(var item in ListOfResxFile) {
        string fn = Path.GetFileName(item);
        lr.Add(new ResourceDescription(fn, () =  > File.OpenRead(item), false));
    }
    EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(jaryan, manifestResources : lr.ToArray());
}
```

I used resgen and converted the *.resx files in the Properties Directory of 
each project to a Resoures.resources file and added this file instead of the *.resx files but it didn't work.

I want to know how to add resources like icons, jpeg files and how to output files.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to compile them to *.resources, with:

```
using (var w = new ResourceWriter(resources))
{
    using (var r = new ResXResourceReader(resx))
    {
        r.BasePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(resx);
        var e = r.GetEnumerator();
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            item = (DictionaryEntry)e.Current;
            w.AddResource(item.Key as string, item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

ResourceName in ResourceDescription need to be default namespace + folder(s) + filename.resources where resource reside. If default namespace is Queue, resource reside in Properties folder and resource file name is Resources.resx then ResourceName is equal to Queue.Properties.Resources.resources

Answer (score 0):

Pass the [`resources` parameter](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/Compilation.cs,1444) to `Emit()`, as a stream in RES format.